# Problem with Sql syntax in Access 2021: Insert Into from multiple records

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is probably something obvious but I think I've been staring at it too long.

My simplified example:
I have table1 with the fields color, name, and flavor.

I have table2 with the fields texture, name, flavor, color.

I'm trying to insert all the records from table2 into table1. Note that fields don't match exactly: table2 has an extra field and one field is in a different position.

So, I get a syntax error for:
INSERT INTO table1(color,name,favor) SELECT color,name,flavor from table2

That's my simplified example. My specific sql statement (copied and pasted) is:

```
INSERT INTO tblDailyInventoryHistorytest(snapshot-Date, fnsku, sku, product-Name, 
quantity, fulfillment-center-id, detailed-disposition) SELECT 
snapshot-date, fnsku,sku, product-Name, quantity, 
fulfillment-center-id, detailed-disposition from tblInventoryLedgerRaw
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I've tried

```
INSERT INTO tblDailyInventoryHistorytest(snapshot-Date, fnsku, sku, product-Name, 
quantity, fulfillment-center-id, detailed-disposition) SELECT  
tblInventoryLedgerRaw.snapshot-date, 
tblInventoryLedgerRaw.fnsku,sku, etc. from tblInventoryLedgerRaw
```

Comment: Object names with spaces or punctuation/special characters or are reserved words must be enclosed in `[ ]`; `[snapshot-date]`. Advise not to use those features in naming convention. Only exception is underscore. Do not need to prefix field names with table names unless same field name is used in multiple tables and included insame query.

Comment: Did not know that! Thanks, that was the problem!!